# android card view layout: use the empty space under an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am creating an android news app. The first layout uses a recylcleview with cardview. Inside each page, the top is the new title, below which is an image on the left and news brief on the right. See the image for an idea:

[image]

**The intention is that the news brief part is to the right of the image, however it also occupies the empty space under the image, if there is any.**

My layout xml looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_thumb"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/news_body"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_thumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
            android:padding="4dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: what do you want with the news brief part ?? Align bottom with the image part ??

Comment: Do you want to fill full area with text ? right and then at bottom of image? this type https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cpUn.png

Comment: @Vishva Dave Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use [**`FlowTextView`**](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)

> A TextView that extends RelativeLayout. The text will wrap around any child views inside the layout.
>
> This widget has basic support for HTML using Html.fromHtml("< your markup ... />") It will recognise links, bold italic etc.

Add `jitpack` to your your `build.gradle` at the end of repositories:

```
repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Add the `dependency`:

```
compile 'com.github.deano2390:FlowTextView:2.0.5'
```

**SAMPLE CODE : HOW TO USE `FlowTextView`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing e"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView
            android:id="@+id/ftv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_thumb"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abc" />


        </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FlowTextView flowTextView = (FlowTextView) findViewById(R.id.ftv);
        Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut dui pellentesque, auctor ipsum id, ultrices nisl. Donec a enim tincidunt, cursus ante in, ultricies arcu. Suspendisse luctus eget neque et dignissim. Mauris libero erat, tincidunt sed fermentum sit amet, porttitor eu nulla. Integer interdum consequat elementum. Ut dictum dignissim sollicitudin. In eu nisl vestibulum, commodo nisl non, fermentum tortor. Pellentesque mattis finibus leo, efficitur porta urna posuere nec.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut dui pellentesque, auctor ipsum id, ultrices nisl. Donec a enim tincidunt, cursus ante in, ultricies arcu. Suspendisse luctus eget neque et dignissim. Mauris libero erat, tincidunt sed fermentum sit amet, porttitor eu nulla. Integer interdum consequat elementum. Ut dictum dignissim sollicitudin. In eu nisl vestibulum, commodo nisl non, fermentum tortor. Pellentesque mattis finibus leo, efficitur porta urna posuere nec.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut dui pellentesque, auctor ipsum id, ultrices nisl. Donec a enim tincidunt, cursus ante in, ultricies arcu. Suspendisse luctus eget neque et dignissim. Mauris libero erat, tincidunt sed fermentum sit amet, porttitor eu nulla. Integer interdum consequat elementum. Ut dictum dignissim sollicitudin. In eu nisl vestibulum, commodo nisl non, fermentum tortor. Pellentesque mattis finibus leo, efficitur porta urna posuere nec.");
        flowTextView.setText(html);

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: this works like a charm, thanks a lot! one more question though, how do i define in the layout attribute a small gap b/w the image and the FlowTextView?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as below u can adjust by the adjustBounds using the separate image view tag